# Changing Link Separator in Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am working on a Vue.js project using Vue Router, and I would like to customize the link separator used in the URL. By default, Vue Router uses a slash ("/") as a separator for route paths.

Is there a way to change this default separator to a different character, such as a semicolon (";")? I have specific URL patterns in mind, and I would like to use a semicolon as the separator in my route paths.

I have reviewed the Vue Router documentation, but I couldn't find information on how to customize the link separator. Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to achieve this in Vue Router?

I want to change the link separator only for diagnostics-loading page

```
// router/index.js

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue';
import DiagnosticsReport from '../components/DiagnosticsReport.vue';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
  },
  {
    path: ';diagnostics-report',  // I want to use a semicolon as the separator here
    name: 'diagnostics-report',
    component: DiagnosticsReport,
  },
  // ... other routes
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Is there a Vue Router configuration option or a workaround that allows changing the link separator to a character other than the default slash?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not just the default for Vue Router, it's the default for the web itself.  A route path becomes the URL. The slash is vital for browsers to understand your URL segments. Regardless, it's an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  What is the actual issue you're trying to solve?  There may be an alternative.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that but this url has to be part of another url and be one of its segments so i want to change the separator to a ;. Is it possible?

Comment: if this url contains a / separator, it will not reroute correctly when added to the other url

Comment: You can replace `/` with `;` in the `path` property of your routes configuration - but if you have nested routes - VueRouter will combine the parent and child routes with a `/` separator and the only way you can change that is by patching VueRouter inside `node_modules`